# OOP Pattern for Shared Functionality (e.g. Logger) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I need recommendations for how to program common functionality into my JavaScript application. For example, there are these classes: Main, Logger, App and Template.

Main creates an instance of App and Logger, then App creates an instance of Template. Main passes a reference of itself into App's init, and App passes it's reference of Main to Template's init. Now, for right or wrong, Template has direct reference to the Logger instance within Main. This is the simplest, but it doesn't seem like proper OOP as any change to logger would require rep-programming every class that invokes the reference.

Alternatively, Template could receive only a reference to App, that has a method to invoke it's reference to Main, which has a method to invoke it's instance of Logger. This seems safer in terms to keeping everyone at bay, but it also means Main will be full of methods simply to access Logger and other classes it manages.

*Not detailed here: I'm using John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance and RequireJS.*

Example 1:

```
var Main = {
  init: function() {
    this.logger = new Logger();
    this.app = new App(this);
  }
}

var Logger = {
  debug: function(message) { 
    console.log(message) 
  }
}

var App = {
  init: function(main) {
    this.template = new Template(main);
  }
}

var Template = {
  init: function(main) {
    main.logger.debug("Hello");
  }
}
```

Example 2:

```
var Main = {
  init: function() {
    this.logger = new Logger();
    this.app = new App(this);
  }
  ,debug: function(message) {
    this.logger.debug(message);
  }
}

var Logger = {
  debug: function(message) { 
    console.log(message);
  }
}

var App = {
  init: function(main) {
    this.main = main;
    this.template = new Template(this);
  }
  ,debug: function(message) {
    this.main.debug(message);
  }
}

var Template = {
  init: function(app) {
    app.debug("Hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/177538)

Comment: Use a mediator , pass the instance of the mediator to each component and  , let the mediator call the actuall logger , broadcasters just need to to pass a message and datas : this.mediator.message("log",{datas:datas}). that's a simple solution , because it will allow you to add other functionalities on the fly ( this.mediator.message("show-alert",message) , etc ...

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer That applies to product recommendations, not technical solutions. I possibly could have used another word as to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I found really useful in my OOP projects with JavaScript use the [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern and [Event Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_monitoring) pattern. It helps a lot also for the Unit Test if you decouple the logic using [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter).